x86 MASM check for palindrome
I’m learning x86 MASM and stuck in a project. The code should be fairly simple but I have no idea what I did wrong, it's supposed to check for Palindrome from an array of characters, but the code always returns EAX = 0 no matter what. I tried different approaches, but it doesn't make any difference.
This is the test.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern"C" {
    int testPalindrome(char[]);
}

int main()
{
    char testString1[] = "birThday";
    char testString2[] = "raceCar";

//for checking result, will do a better presentation
    cout << testString1 << ' ' << testPalindrome(testString1) << endl;
    cout << testString2 << ' ' << testPalindrome(testString2) << endl;
    return 0;
}


and this is the .asm
.686
.model flat

.code

_testPalindrome PROC    
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp     ; stack pointer to ebp
    
    mov ebx,[ebp+8]     ; address of first array element
    xor ecx,ecx
    xor dl,dl
    mov al,223

arrayEnd:                   
    cmp [ebx+ecx],dl
    je continue             
    inc ecx
    jmp arrayEnd
            
continue:                   
    mov edx,0               
    mov edi,ecx             
    dec edi         ;to not include the \0 at the end
    shr ecx,1       ;to traverse only to middle of string       
    
palindromeCheck:
    cmp ecx, 0
    je yesPalindrome        

    ;compare, convert to uppercase but don't change the original string
    mov cl,[ebx+edx]        
    and cl,al           
    mov dl,[ebx+edi]        
    and dl,al           

    cmp cl,[ebx+edi]
    jne notPalindrome

    sub ecx, 1              
    add edx, 1              
    sub edi, 1              
    jmp palindromeCheck     

yesPalindrome:
    mov eax,1
    jmp allDone

notPalindrome:
    mov eax,0

allDone:
    pop ebp
    ret

_testPalindrome ENDP

END


mov dl,[ebx+edi] <-- dl is the least significant byte of edx, so you're overwriting one of your string offsets.

There are multiple reasons why your code fails to discover palindromes.

Since the 8-bit register CL is part of the 32-bit register ECX, each time you execute mov cl,[ebx+edx] you are also erroneously changing the loop counter.
Since the 8-bit register DL is part of the 32-bit register EDX, each time you execute mov dl,[ebx+edi] you are also erroneously changing the left hand side string offset.
Even though the and cl,al and and dl,al instructions perform UCase on both sides, the cmp cl,[ebx+edi] is effectively ignoring the UCase from the right hand side.

One possible solution
    mov   ebx, [ebp + 8] ; Address of first array element
    xor   ecx, ecx
arrayLen:
    cmp   byte ptr [ebx + ecx], 0
    lea   ecx, [ecx + 1]
    jne   arrayLen
    dec   ecx
          
    xor   esi, esi       ; Left hand side offset is 0               
    lea   edi, [ecx - 1] ; Right hand side offset
    shr   ecx, 1         ; To traverse only to middle of string       
    jz    yesPalindrome
palindromeCheck:
    movzx eax, byte ptr [ebx + esi]        
    or    eax, 32
    movzx edx, byte ptr [ebx + edi]        
    or    edx, 32  
    cmp   al, dl
    jne   notPalindrome
    dec   edi
    inc   esi
    dec   ecx
    jnz   palindromeCheck     
yesPalindrome:
    lea   eax, [ecx + 1] ; -> EAX=1
    jmp   allDone
notPalindrome:
    xor   eax, eax       ; -> EAX=0
allDone:

Please notice that through using or edx, 32 I have chosen to LCase the characters rather than using and edx, 223 to UCase. The comparison works just as good, but while avoiding writing partial registers and because of the sign-extendable byte, this or encodes in 2 bytes while this and requires 5 bytes. In general shorter code is faster code.
